# @Async @Aspect @AfterReturnung. My method has HttpServletRequest object as method argument, but able to access it my aop method

Tags: java, spring, servlets, asynchronous, aspect

I am trying to log HttpServletRequest content through aop in async mode. The method on which pointcut in implement has HttpServletRequest  as method argument. I am not able to access it in async mode, though the code works fine without the @Async annotation.

```
@Async
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.web.dto.util.response.impl.ResponseImpl.prepareResponseDTO(..))", returning = "object")
    public void logSearchJSON(JoinPoint joinPoint, final Object object) {
        try {
            List<Object> objects = getActivityParams(joinPoint);

            UserActivity userPersonalization = null;
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) objects.get(0);
            if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains(UserActivityConstant.filter)) 

httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() returns null.
```

It was working fine without the @Async annotation

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly declared a task executor?

You can do it in that way in your Spring context:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="TaskExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="TaskExecutor"
                   pool-size="2-5"
                   queue-capacity="50"
                   keep-alive="120"
                   rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

You can also do it in a @Configuration class.